# Messages lost when Kafka nodes are restarted

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm running a 3-node Kafka cluster on AWS.

Kafka version: **0.10.2.1**
Zookeeper version: **3.4**

While performing a few stability tests I've noticed that messages get lost when I take the leader node down.

**These are the steps to reproduce the issue:**

Create a topic with replication-factor 3 which should make the data available on all 3 nodes.:

```
~ $ docker run --rm -ti ches/kafka bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper "10.2.31.10:2181,10.2.31.74:2181,10.2.31.138:2181" --create --topic stackoverflow --replication-factor 3 --partitions 20
Created topic "stackoverflow".
~ $ docker run --rm -ti ches/kafka bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper "10.2.31.10:2181,10.2.31.74:2181,10.2.31.138:2181" --describe --topic stackoverflow
Topic:stackoverflow    PartitionCount:20    ReplicationFactor:3    Configs:
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 0    Leader: 1    Replicas: 1,2,0    Isr: 1,2,0
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 1    Leader: 2    Replicas: 2,0,1    Isr: 2,0,1
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 2    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0,1,2    Isr: 0,1,2
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 3    Leader: 1    Replicas: 1,0,2    Isr: 1,0,2
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 4    Leader: 2    Replicas: 2,1,0    Isr: 2,1,0
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 5    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0,2,1    Isr: 0,2,1
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 6    Leader: 1    Replicas: 1,2,0    Isr: 1,2,0
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 7    Leader: 2    Replicas: 2,0,1    Isr: 2,0,1
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 8    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0,1,2    Isr: 0,1,2
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 9    Leader: 1    Replicas: 1,0,2    Isr: 1,0,2
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 10    Leader: 2    Replicas: 2,1,0    Isr: 2,1,0
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 11    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0,2,1    Isr: 0,2,1
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 12    Leader: 1    Replicas: 1,2,0    Isr: 1,2,0
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 13    Leader: 2    Replicas: 2,0,1    Isr: 2,0,1
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 14    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0,1,2    Isr: 0,1,2
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 15    Leader: 1    Replicas: 1,0,2    Isr: 1,0,2
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 16    Leader: 2    Replicas: 2,1,0    Isr: 2,1,0
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 17    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0,2,1    Isr: 0,2,1
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 18    Leader: 1    Replicas: 1,2,0    Isr: 1,2,0
    Topic: stackoverflow    Partition: 19    Leader: 2    Replicas: 2,0,1    Isr: 2,0,1
```

Start producing on that topic with the following code:

```
import time
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['10.2.31.10:9092' ,'10.2.31.74:9092' ,'10.2.31.138:9092'])

try:
    count = 0
    while True:
        producer.send('stackoverflow', 'message')
        producer.flush()
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Sent %s messages." % count
```

At this point I kill one of the machines and wait until it returns to cluster.

When it's back I stop the producer and consume all the messages from that topic.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('stackoverflow',
                            bootstrap_servers=['10.2.31.10:9092' ,'10.2.31.74:9092' ,'10.2.31.138:9092'],
                            auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                            enable_auto_commit=False)
try:
    count = 0
    for message in consumer:
        count += 1
        print message
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Received %s messages." % count
```

Two messages that have been sent are missing. The producer didn't return any errors.

```
kafka $ python producer.py
Sent 762 messages.

kafka $ python consumer.py
Received 760 messages.
```

I'm new to Kafka so I'd really appreciate any ideas for debugging this further. Or instructions for making the cluster more resilient.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I figured the reason for lost messages was insufficient number of retries. After reading a few blog posts about highly-available kafka, I noticed that people are recommending really high values for the "retries" parameter.

In python that would be:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=[...], retries=sys.maxint)
```

I performed my tests again confirmed that no messages were lost.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into exactly the same issue some time ago. During investigation I found interesting feature: `flush()` method returns after each message in the buffer is sent **or request resulted in error**, as stated in the [documentation](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html#kafka.KafkaProducer.flush).

I mitigated it by:

1. Disabling `unclean.leader.election.enabled` on brokers (if not set, it's `true` in kafka<0.11 and `false` in kafka>=0.11, so you need to set it to false on your 0.10.2)
2. Chaging async producer (send & flush) to synchronous one: `producer.send(...).get()`
3. Added parameter `retries=5` to KafkaProducer init (to make producer survive broker shutdown).

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mariusz!

I upgraded the cluster to 0.11 and added retries=5 parameter. That didn't solve the issue.

Changing to synchronous producer did though. I get an exception when send() fails so I can retry it manually. The thing is though, that's not a perfect solution. I would like to be able to keep async producer because it makes the code much simpler.

Is it really not possible to use async producer without downtime?

Comment: To be clear - all three steps from my post was required (that's why only setting retries=5 and disabling unclear election did not solve the issue). Using the method was the only that worked for me. AFAIR, in java/scala API, the `send` method has something like "on-failure callback", so you can be notified whether message was not delivered and (for example) save it in a file and recover from it after a while. But I don't see similar feature in python.